# Neo4j count is not predictable

Tags: neo4j, count

Using the Preferential attachment example in the guides, I have a node C with degree 3 and node E with degree 1

```
UNWIND [["A", "C"], ["A", "B"], ["B", "D"],
    ["B", "C"], ["B", "E"], ["C", "D"]] AS pair
MERGE (n1:Node {name: pair[0]})
MERGE (n2:Node {name: pair[1]})
MERGE (n1)-[:FRIENDS]-(n2)
```

and when I try a simple degree query for node E I get the correct answer.  But when I add another node, the answer changes to 3

```
MATCH (e:Node {name: 'E'})--(othere)
RETURN e,othere, count(othere)
```

returns 1 for count(othere)

```
MATCH (c:Node {name: 'C'})--(otherc)
MATCH (e:Node {name: 'E'})--(othere)
RETURN e,othere, count(othere)
```

returns 3 for count(othere).  Why should this be?

Answer (score 1):

In your last query's `RETURN` clause, the `COUNT` [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) counts the *number of result rows* that have the same `e` and `othere` values. With your sample data, there are 3 such result rows.

Here is one way to get a correct count of the number of relationships between `e` and `othere`:

```
MATCH (c:Node {name: 'C'})--(otherc)
MATCH (e:Node {name: 'E'})-[r]-(othere)
RETURN e, othere, COUNT(DISTINCT r)
```

[DISCUSSION]

In general, there can be any number of relationships between any 2 nodes. So, to make this a more general discussion, suppose the "E" node has 2 relationships to the "B" node (and no other relationships).

- My query would return a correct `COUNT` (degree) of 2. Remember, the *degree* of a node is its *number of relationships*.
- A similar-looking query that returned `COUNT(DISTINCT othere)` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT r)` would return 1, which is incorrect.
- Your second query's return clause (`RETURN e, othere, COUNT(othere)`)  clause would return a `COUNT` of 6 (because there'd be 6 result rows with `othere`).

I hope this helps to make clear why I used `COUNT(DISTINCT r)`. You should also read the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) documentation carefully.

Comment: True, and certainly a very reliable method.  However, I am curious as to what is going on under the hood that makes my original two cases differ.

Comment: This is actually a very complex subject. I have added a discussion to my answer.